SwiftUI - Grid/Table Layout for user input (Rows) -
Trying to make a SWiftUI layout, end goal will be to have it look sort of like a table view. Right now I am using a grid. Within the Grid are Rows of (usually) a Label(), and 3 TextFields(). This is my current code for it, right now it looks okay, however when i type in the textfields after a certain amount of character have been inputed it starts to expand the cut the label and other textfield out of site. Any advise?
Grid {
   // Basic Empty Weight Row
   GridRow {
      Label("Basic Empty", systemImage: "")
         .labelStyle(.titleOnly)
                            
      TextField("W", text: $basicEmpW)
      TextField("A", text: $basicEmpA)
      TextField("MOM", text: $basicEmpMOM)
   }
   .padding(.horizontal, 10)
   .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                    
   // Pilot Row
   GridRow {
     Label("Pilot / Co-Pilot", systemImage: "star.fill")
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        .lineLimit(0)
                            
     TextField("W", text: $pcpW)
     TextField("A", text: $pcpA)
     TextField("MOM", text: $pcpMOM)
   }
   .padding(.horizontal, 10)
   .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
   
   // Zero Fuel Weight Row
   GridRow {
     Label("Zero Fuel", systemImage: "gym.bag.fill")
        Label(zerofW, systemImage: "gym.bag.fill")
   }

https://imgur.com/a/2RuLxdV <--- gif of what happening when i type in the TextField

How do you want the text field to behave otherwise? If you want it to truncate the text, fix its width using .frame(width: 50) for example.

The text normally wouldn't get that big big im seeing after about 5-6 characters its starts to move the labels like shown in the gif. how can i have it not expand like that until an excessive amount typed into the textfield?
Is there a way to style the full grid in a more efficient way?
